# The interval set for subscription to the method from a component is not getting triggered

Tags: angular

I am implementing a functionality in the angular8 client application that checks if the .net core API is available every 10 seconds. I have basically set a timer for 10 seconds
that will ping the method in the service that checks for availability. This logic is created in the Offline component. For some reason I don't see the polling happening until I stop the service. Could you let me know where I am
going wrong ?

The Offline component is declared in the declarations section in the App.Module

Connection Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ConfigurationService } from "./configuration.service";

@Injectable()
export class ConnectionService {

    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, private configurationService: ConfigurationService) { }

    checkIfCoreApiIsAvailable() {
        var pingUrl = this.configurationService.baseUrl + "/api/online";
        return this.httpClient.get(pingUrl, { observe: 'response' });
    }
}
```

Offline component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'not-found',
    templateUrl: './offline.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./offline.component.css'],
    animations: [fadeInOut]
})
export class OfflineComponent implements OnInit {
    subscription: Subscription;
    pingInterval: number;

    constructor(private connectionService: ConnectionService) {
        // Check if Core-API service is Online or Offline
        //this.pingInterval = environment.corePingIntervalSeconds;

        const source = timer(0, environment.corePingIntervalSeconds * 1000);
        source.subscribe(() => {
            this.connectionService
           .checkIfCoreApiIsAvailable()
           .pipe(first())
           .subscribe(resp  => {
             if (resp.status === 200 ) {
               console.log(true)
             } else {
               console.log(false)
             }
           }, err => console.log(err));
         });
        }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        if(this.subscription) {
             this.subscription.unsubscribe();
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate what exactly do you mean with "For some reason I don't see the polling happening until I stop the service."

Comment: What I meant is the desired functionality is that this sevice check should kick in as soon as the user  logged in the application. That is the application is loaded. It doesnt happen so.

Comment: To my understanding this component doesnt get loaded unless the user is directed to the offline component and the component is loaded. Am i right.

Comment: Right, `OfflineComponent` is not instantiated unless it is somewhere in DOM

Comment: @Tom, when you are loading `OfflineComponent`, is it loaded from `route` or `selector` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that the component is added to some template:

```
<not-found></not-found>
```

You should remove the `.pipe(first())` line.

You are acting only on the first iteration. See the doc for more info:
https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/first.html

**EDIT:**

As you said in comments you are not interested on adding this functionality as a component because you don't need/want the HTML associated to it. That's why I think that you should use the service. This could be an option:

Modify the service to include the functionality that was in the component in a new method for example `startChecking`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ConfigurationService } from "./configuration.service";

@Injectable()
export class ConnectionService {

    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, private configurationService: ConfigurationService) { }

    startChecking() { 

        const source = timer(0, environment.corePingIntervalSeconds * 1000);
        source.subscribe(() => {
            this.checkIfCoreApiIsAvailable()
                .subscribe(resp  => {
                    if (resp.status === 200 ) {
                        console.log(true)
                    } else {
                        console.log(false)
                    }
                }, err => console.log(err));
            });
        }
    }

    private checkIfCoreApiIsAvailable() {
        var pingUrl = this.configurationService.baseUrl + "/api/online";
        return this.httpClient.get(pingUrl, { observe: 'response' });
    }
}
```

Then, use that service on your app start:

```
/// ...
class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor (private connectionService : ConnectionService ) {
        //
    }

    ngOnInit() {    
        /// ...    
        this.connectionService.startChecking(); 
    }  

    /// ...
}
/// ...
```

Comment: I dont think this is right as logic in the offline component doesnt get executed in the first place. I did comment that line to check but there wasnt any difference

Comment: If that the case ensure you add your component to your app. None of your components will be executed if you don't add them to a template.

Comment: So do you think the its better to add it tin the app.component.html

Comment: It depends on where do you need it to work. If you need to make it work in the whole app you should add it to the app.component.html or add the logic to the app.component.ts file.

Comment: i would move this functionality into service and start the polling after user logged in, or when the polling should start when application is initialized then i would start the polling in application initializer

Comment: The reason why i created a component is to display the maintenance page html which is part of that component

Comment: I cannot use the option of adding <not-found></not-found> component to the app.component.html as the not-found has its own html which i dont want to display

Comment: I updated the answer @Tom, to use a service. I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't load the OfflineComponent you should consider using this logic within a service which you can provide in root